# Unable to get double.TryParse to work in Linq Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, lambda, expression-trees

I am trying to create a dynamic where clause using Linq Expressions for an IQueryable data source. I can't get the TryParse function to work in one of the Expressions. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
IQueryable<trial_global> globalTrials = _trialsRepository.GlobalDataFiltered(filterId).AsQueryable();

BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static;
MethodInfo tryParseMethod = typeof(double).GetMethod("TryParse", bindingFlags, null, new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(double).MakeByRefType() }, null);
Expression tempN = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "tempN");
Expression left = Expression.Call(tryParseMethod, new[] { metricReference, tempN });

Expression right = Expression.Constant(true);
Expression predicateBody = Expression.Equal(left, right);

MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
                            typeof(Queryable),
                            "Where",
                            new Type[] { globalTrials.ElementType },
                            globalTrials.Expression,
                            Expression.Lambda<Func<trial_global, bool>>(predicateBody, new ParameterExpression[] { pe })
                            );

var results = globalTrials.Provider.CreateQuery<trial_global>(whereCallExpression);
```

Everything works fine until `results` gets assigned where I get the following error:

```
variable 'tempN' of type 'System.Double' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

What am I missing here? I suspect it has to do with the 2nd parameter in the double.TryParse function being an `out` parameter.

**UPDATE:**

I got around the issue by creating a static function which does the TryParse and calling this static function from the Expression:

```
public static bool IsStringNumeric(string checkStr)
{
    double num = 0;
    return double.TryParse(checkStr, out num);
}

public IQueryable<trial_global> GetTrials(IQueryable<trial_global> globalTrials, Metric metric)
{
    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(trial_global), "trial_global");
    MemberExpression metricReference = Expression.Property(pe, metric.metric_name);

    Expression predicateBody = Expression.Call(typeof(GlobalTrialsRepository).GetMethod("IsStringNumeric", new Type[] { typeof(string) }), metricReference);

    MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable),
                "Where",
                new Type[] { globalTrials.ElementType },
                globalTrials.Expression,
                Expression.Lambda<Func<trial_global, bool>>(predicateBody, new ParameterExpression[] { pe })
                );

    return globalTrials.Provider.CreateQuery<trial_global>(whereCallExpression);
}
```

Is this approach ok? Does anyone see any disadvantages of doing it like this?

Comment: If you were to write the predicate as lambda expression, what would it look like?

Comment: There is no need to generate `x == true`.

Comment: Also, few LINQ providers will handle `TryParse()`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek This is the lambda expression I have used before `double number; var res = globalTrials.Where(a => double.TryParse(a.Column1, out number));` When I put `res` in the watch I see the following `argument` under `expression`: `a => TryParse(a.Subjects_Per_Month, value(Application.Services.TrialGridSourceService+<>c__DisplayClass2).number)`

Answer (score 0):

Tryparse use out parameter for the check. Create an extension method with the tryparse and then call the extension method from linq

Comment: He can create the expression then but it will not run with pretty much any provider.

Comment: What provider understands double.TryParse anyways?

Comment: Sorry I though he wanted a function to verify for a regular linq statement

Answer (score 0):

Linq queries are deferred until a ToXXXX() is called on it. You can, therefore, define the Where statement as a Linq method chain and then just call .ToList or whatever to get the value.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are saying I should do something like `var res = _datasource.Where(a => a.Col1 == 'xyz').ToList()` The reason I can't do this is that the column (`Col1`) that I want to query is not known beforehand. It will come dynamically hence the need to create the dynamic expression.